# How to declare and initialize user defined table type?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created this user table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntArray] AS TABLE
(
    IntValue INT
)
```

I also created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnProcessIntArray]
(
    @IntArray as dbo.intArray READONLY
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- Input is table of int values
-- Output example : '1,2,3,4'
...
END
```

now I need to test a function but I don't know how, I tried

```
SELECT dbo.fnProcessIntArray((SELECT 1))
-- Error: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with IntArray

SELECT dbo.fnProcessIntArray((SELECT 1,2,3,4))
-- Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

How can I DECLARE @intArray as dbo.IntArray ?

Comment: `DECLARE @x dbo.intArray; INSERT @x VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4); SELECT dbo.fnProcessIntArray(@x);`

Comment: Please post this as an answer for everybody to see.